# Texbox with button in it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

How can I create an TextBox in WPF ( With XAML ) that there is an button inside it, Just like Google Chrome Adressbar.
I want somethings like the picture below :

[image]

And then how can I change the position of the button to the right and left ? ( I'm  using C# )

Comment: Create your own `UserControl` for such purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this :

```
<Border x:Name="TextboxBorder" BorderBrush="#FFB8AAAA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="2"        Margin="3,1.5,4.084,1.5" Height="27" Background="White" CornerRadius="3">
    <Grid x:Name="TextboxGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3.5,4.833,4.5,3.5" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="  {DynamicResource      SearchButtonStyle}" >
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/search.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <TextBox Padding="0,1.2,0,0" x:Name="txt" Margin="1.541,0.5,2.041,0.5"       TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="سلام" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="16"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

And the Button style is :

```
 <Style x:Key="SearchButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Border BorderThickness="0" Margin="1.875,0.5,1.75,-0.375" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"     Width="16" Height="16"/>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
              <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
              </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And Then WPF Rocks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could nest the button inside a Grid on top of the TextBox, since it sounds like you only need to use this once:

e.g.

```
<Grid>
  <TextBox Text="Hello" />
  <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Click Me" />
</Grid>
```

The only issue with this is that the text will show under the button. An alternative is to make your own usercontrol or to edit the controltemplate of the textbox (but this will probably not have the functionality you want).

I'd create a textbox in the left column of a 2 column grid, then the button in the right column. Then remove the background and border on the textbox and put this background/border on the grid. This will give the appearance of a textbox with a button in where the text can't go underneath the button

e.g.

```
    <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Height="30">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Text="Hello World this is a really long bit of text that wont go underneath the button (it will get clipped)"></TextBox>
            <Button Content="Click me" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

Only problem you have with that is that you don't get the chrome hover effect etc etc. Usercontrol with control template is your best option, but this gives you some ideas

Comment: When The textbox got focus the trick appears... Can u please tell me how can I do it by creating new Usercontrol ( I have no experience with Usercontrols  )